# Problem building python ros2 humble packages

Tags: setuptools, deprecation-warning, ros2, colcon

I'm starting to use ros on an Ubuntu Virtual Machine.

I installed it following the official website instruction.

But, when i run colcon build to build a ros python package and a cpp package, and i got this message from the python package build.

it's a waning, but it looks like something you really want to solve, but I don't know how to solve it... (or if it's necessary to be solved because it will cause troubles; or if it's not important)

```
Starting >>> cpp_pkg 
Starting >>> py_pkg
Finished <<< cpp_pkg [0.48s]                                              
--- stderr: py_pkg                   
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
warnings.warn(
---
Finished <<< py_pkg [0.96s]

Summary: 2 packages finished [1.14s]
1 package had stderr output: py_pkg
```

i installed and upgraded setuptools

i installed colcon-python-setup-py

i checked other stuffs and upgrade all python packages

i had already installed anaconda3 before installing ros, but it shouldn't be a issue, should it?

Comment: are you sure you have the latest versions of everything? might want to ask this on superuser.com. Me personally, would completely ignore the warning and just carry on :))